# Finding the contact point of two spheres

Tags: collision-resolution, sphere

Is there a way to get the normal and depth of two spheres that have collided.

I know that it is something to do with the center and radius of two spheres but I am not sure what

Comment: Downvoter, can you please explain why you downvoted. Feedback will be appreciated so I can modify the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably the simplest 3D collision check.

Distance between sphere centers is `length(c1.center - c2.center)`

Depth is distance - radius1 - radius2 = `length(c1.center - c2.center) - c1.radius - c2.radius`

Normal is `normalized(c1.center - c2.center)` for c2 and the inverse of that for c1.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that the point of contact on the surface of the sphere is `c1.center - normal * c1.radius` / `c2.center + normal * c2.radius)`. If the spheres just touch without penetrating, then these two surface contact points will be the same.